# CORBA local object not allowed exception using JAVA

Tags: java, corba, idl

I am working on a project which requires CORBA understanding, I am reading through web and understanding that. I have been given an `idl` file which I compiled using `idlj` from the JDK.

Server is already implemented. I have to make connection and read data from it.

It has generated all helper classes, stubs and skeletons. I will make connections using `IIOP` . I am using the Helper class to narrow and then calling functions. Currently is is giving me

> ORBUtilSystemException localObjectNotAllowed()

Any ideas why this problem occurs? Where I am doing wrong? There are very few resources and tutorials related to CORBA.

Comment: Please provide your idl or at least the code that leads to the exception you posted.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using CORBA for a client/server implementation.  When you were given an IDL, are you using it to implement a server or using it as a client to talk to an existing server?

If you are implementing a client application, what you need is to establish a connection with the server.  You can do so in multiple ways such as object discovery or if the server is on a well-known address then you can create your CORBA object directly.

I would recommend you to try JacORB http://www.jacorb.org/ that is another CORBA implementation in Java.  It has some demo application that you can try and learn from there.  Their documentation is also up-to-date so it should give you a good starting point.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply. Server is already implemented, I am using IDL to create client.  Though I am near to it , the current problem goes to implementation of callbacks. Will look at jacorb.

Comment: The JDK-ORB is not the problem here, thus a link to JacORB would not help either. Giving an example here would help